# Verification methods of IDP in SAML2 IDP initiated login

Tags: identity, saml

What are the methods we can use to verify Identity Provider in Identity Provider initiated login in SAML2 Single sign on (SAML2 SSO)? Can any one who has access to IDP private key are able to create a trusted connection to SP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDP is typically verified by a a cryptographic signature on the messages it sends to the SP. These are produced using the IPD private key. If the private key is lost anyone could predent to be the IDP.